# How do i detect changes in a object?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have this app that loops thru my AD and I would like it to notify me on changes. IE if someone changed their email, a user was added and so on. 
I was thinking of checksum DirectoryEntry object that gets the root AD object with all its children but i cant wrap my head around it.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = 
    new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, username, password);
```

the app im making is a windows service that will check AD every hour for changes, sizeof is a nogo as microsoft dont want me to know the size of this managed object. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashCode? override the [Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) property?

Comment: While this won't guarantee to capture ALL modifications, when the hash is different, you can guarantee that the AD record has changed.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the [`DirectorySynchronization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysynchronization.aspx) class.  When searching the AD using `DirectorySearcher` with the [`DirectorySearcher.DirectorySynchronization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.directorysynchronization.aspx) property set, a cookie is generated that you can save to a file or database.  Using this cookie in following similar searches will ensure that only objects that have changed between two searches are returned by `DirectorySearcher`.  IIRC it will even tell you which properties have changed.